# Turning UILabel to NSString with same size and alignment

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsstring

Is there any way to make a NSString out of a UILabel while keeping the size and alignment? I need this for a section header in a UITableView.

Comment: Also, I am not sure I understand you correctly. Do you want to copy a string from an existing UILabel?

Answer (score 1):

An `NSString` has neither font size nor alignment, it's just a series of characters.

You can however use a `UILabel` as part of a section header view.

Comment: Implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` instead of `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` (which you are probably using now).